# Are there natural languages with required, grammatical, emotional context markers?

Tags: list-of-languages

Having seen some examples of ANADEW *(A natlang's already dunnit, except worse)* I was wondering if that statement applies to required, grammatical, emotional context markers, such as the conlangs of

- [Láadan and its emotional intent suffixes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/L%C3%A1adan/L%C3%A1adan_Grammar_Reference#Extensions) - Although, "Neutral" doesn't have its own marker, and is marked by the lack of a mark.

> You can attach a suffix to each of these [sentence type indicators] in order to further specify the speaker/writer's intentions:
>
> - -(None)     Said neutrally
> - -d  Said in anger
> - -th     Said in pain
> - -li     Said in love
> - -lan    Said in celebration
> - -da     Said in jest
> - -de     Said in narrative
> - -di     Said in teaching
> - -du     Said in poetry
> - -ya     Said in fear

- [Hymmnos - New Testament of Pastalie dialect](https://conlang.fandom.com/wiki/Hymmnos#Emotion_Verbs) - Every verb has a marker specifying the reason for it, with Neutral / Mindlessness likely being "N":

> At a first look, words like hYEmmEr or fOwOrYUn look like crazy strings of letters from someone typing with the Shift key held and released rapidly. In actuality, all emotion verbs are made from 2 components.
>
> The first component is the "base verb", which look like these: h.m.m.r., f.w.r.n., a.u.k., c.z. It consists of two or more lower case letters with a dot "." called "bank period" in between each character. A base verb is a complete word and has meaning, but it does not contain any emotion (and Hymmnos is all about expressing emotion).
>
> The second component is the "emotion vowel", which are those upper case letters you see in emotion verbs. Their function is to express the emotions associated with the action of the verb.
> Here is a list of [basic definitions of] emotion vowels and their meanings, [with a "Y" before them meaning the audience is a subject, and "L" before *that* meaning the world's population is a subject]:
>
> - A - Strength, concentration, doing one's best.
> - I - Pain, agony, fear, feeling of wanting to run away.
> - U - Sadness, worry, (sometimes means caring too).
> - E - Happiness, pleasure.
> - O - Anger, malice.
> - N - Absent-mindedness, relaxation, (sometimes means negative).

But does any natural language mark emotional context in this way?

Comment: Do you count pejorative markers? The creator of Láadan cites these as inspiration for the emotional context markers. Or, for an English example, does saying "ughhh" after an utterance count as an emotional context marker for disgust or frustration?

Comment: @Draconis - I'd say no? It's too tied into the idea of a general expression of emotion, like crying and squealing.

Comment: ‘Marker’ is a very loose term. English has clear markers to convey condescension and disgust, for example, but they’re based on intonation and emphasising specific words; e.g., saying “You actually _like_ that?”, with a strong emphasis and a rising tone on _like_ that carries over into a continued high tone on _that_, quite unambiguously marks the speaker’s emotion/attitude. Would you count that? Or are you looking specifically for _grammatical_ markers – affixes, conjugations, particles, etc.?

Comment: Do [sentence-final particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence-final_particle) count?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Good point! Added more adjectives to pin things down. How's it?

Comment: @Nardog - Closer, but no. Made an edit.

Comment: What do you mean by required? Like if I'm impartial to the statement I'm making I must use a neutral marker?

Comment: @Nardog - Well, I'd accept something like that, since I've got Hymmnos as a basis, where emotion is only needed when using verbs. Still not sure how Láadan works, but it does seem to require some emotion with every utterance? ... As long as emotion is a required part of expression in a majority of common sentences, I'd accept it? ... Hard to say without a example answer?

Comment: In Russian, to express endearment when talking to babies and very young children everything is pronounced with very rounded and protruded lips and all the vowels are heavily fronted. This gives the speech a distinct affective/emotional coloring called _сюсюканье_ [sʲuˈsʲukɐnʲjə] ~ “soo-soo’ing”. I'm sure other languages also have this or a similar thing.

Comment: I quick-checked [evidentiality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidentiality) and [mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_mood) and did not find exact matches for this.

Comment: @YellowSky - That's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_talk - Perhaps?

Comment: @Malady - Yes, exactly.

Comment: Take a look at Sapir's ["Abnormal types of speech in Nootka"](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=inu.30000087080705&view=1up&seq=5)